# Regex select all content within an XML node

Tags: regex, xml, google-sheets

Currently I'm trying to select all the data within the node `"<XIMAGE5></XIMAGE5>"`. That data can consist of a mix of numbers and letters, they also have `*.jpg` at the end of each one.

Example:

```
<XIMAGE5>KGNVS66x.jpg</XIMAGE5>
```

I'm trying to select every single one, so I can prefix a URL in front of each so it is like the following:

```
<XIMAGE5>http://fakeaccount.s3.amazonaws.com/images/KGNVS66x.jpg</XIMAGE5>
```

I don't know enough about regex to even begin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To add something to the start of a tag's contents, match the (zero width) position immediately after the open tag using:

```
(?<=<XIMAGE5>)
```

And "replace" it with the content you want to inject.

---

To select the tag's contents, use look arounds and a reluctant quantifier:

```
(?<=<XIMAGE5>).*?(?=</XIMAGE5>)
```

The look behind/ahead assert (without consuming input) that there's an open/close tag and the `.*?` consumes as little as possible (so it doesn't run past a close tag to the last close tag).

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/wRiI6Y4alO).

Comment: Hmm this seems to select the whole node within Atom :(

Comment: @user3082823 oops. Was missing a bracket. Fixed now, with demo link.

Comment: If I was going to add text in-front of the selection. Would I select the text using your regex function then do "www.google.com/$1"? Would that add google.com infront of each one?

Comment: @user3082823 do you want to match the whole tag *including* the tags, or only the contents *between* the tags?

Comment: Only the content between the tags, it works perfectly just don't understand how to store and add to regex

Comment: Or should I say - how to prefix text on to each selection using atom

Comment: @user Please add an example to your question of the "before" content and the "after replacement" content so we all know exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Bohemian, it is within the question. Selecting the XIMAGE5 content and adding the S3 URL before each one.

Comment: @user3082823 see updated answer. Basically regex replace `"(?<=<XIMAGE5>)"` with `"http://fakeaccount.s3.amazonaws.com/images/"`